# Google Recaptcha v2 verification failed on server side

Tags: java, javascript, spring, recaptcha

I have faced one issue with recaptcha v2.
I completed my code with validations on client and server side.
But interesting one i have noticed in this recaptcha v2 is
if i'm a guest authenticating my login page(demo) with out login of any other google account in another tab, it is showing number(image) to enter(type) and validate.
if i'm a guest authenticating my login page(demo) with login into one of my google account in another tab, it is not showing any captcha and validating "i'm not a robot!"..
Can anybody tell me whats going on???

Login.jsp

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>


<form><div class="g-recaptcha" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div></form>
```

Controller.java: Im calling this method in login controller method

```
    public boolean captchaValidationAndLogin(
        String recaptchaResponse, HttpServletRequest request) {
    try{
        String secretParameter="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        System.out.println(recaptchaResponse);

        // Send get request to Google reCaptcha server with secret key
        URL url = new URL(
                "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret="
                        +secretParameter+"&response="+recaptchaResponse+"&remoteip="
                        +request.getRemoteAddr());  
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        String line, outputString = "";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        outputString += line;
        }
    System.out.println("Status in string: "+outputString);
    // Convert response into Object
    CaptchaStatus status=new Gson().fromJson(outputString, CaptchaStatus.class);
        if(status.isSuccess()){
            System.out.println("success");
            return true;
            }
        else{
            System.out.println("failed");
            return false;
            }
    }//try
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
        }
}
```

LoginController.java:

```
if(loginAttempts >= 3)
    {
        /* Captcha token validation*/
        captcha = false;
        //System.out.println("Before calling captcha method");
        String recaptchaResponse = request.getParameter(
                "g-recaptcha-response");
        captcha= captchaValidationAndLogin(recaptchaResponse, request);
        /*System.out.println(
                "Captcha value after 3 login attempts:"+captcha);*/
    }
```

Comment: It seems you don't understand how reCAPTCHA actually works. If you aren't exhibiting suspicious behaviour then you aren't required to verify with a CAPTCHA. If Google thinks that you are a bot however, it makes you solve a CAPTCHA to prove that you are not

Comment: When i'm checking the CAPTCHA checkbox it is saying "I'm not a robot" without popup of images or numbers to verify...@JamesMassey

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how reCAPTCHA works. See the video Google put out: http://youtu.be/jwslDn3ImM0

Comment: Is it possible to enable popup the numbers to be verified everytime whenever the reCAPTCHA is loaded into my page...because I must verify the user with Recaptcha.....(In view of my application) @JamesMassey